# How to display a list pandas DataFrame cell as multiple lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Not sure if this makes any sense but essentially I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

| col 1 (str) | col 2 (int) | col 3 (list) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | num | [text(01),text(02),...,text(n)] |
| name2 | num | [text(11),text(12),...,text(m)] |

Where one of the columns is a list of strings, in this case col 3, and n!=m.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to display them in a more readable manner, such as:

| col 1 (str) | col 2 (int) | col 3 (list) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | num | text(01) |
|  |  | ... |
|  |  | text(n) |
| name2 | num | text(11) |
|  |  | ... |
|  |  | text(m) |

I appreciate this looks messy but my intention is for all the texts to be displayed in one cell, just with line breaks, rather than being split across multiple rows as the table above shows.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on the `col3` with list values like

```
In [44]: df.explode('col3')
Out[44]: 
   col1  col2       col3
0  name1  num   text(01)
0  name1  num   text(02)
1  name2  num   text(11)
1  name2  num   text(12)
```

Could then `set_index`

```py
In [53]: df.explode('col3').set_index(['col1', 'col2'])
Out[53]: 
                 col3
col1  col2
name1 num    text(01)
      num    text(02)
name2 num    text(11)
      num    text(12)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **explode** - function in pandas - It's partially solving the problem - but in this case [col1] + [col2] will be duplicated.

The explode() function is used to transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating the index values.

```
df1 = df1.explode('col3name')
df1.explode('col3name')
```

Initial:

[image]

After explode:

[image]